# How to avoid Spring boot test case failing with LF and CRLF while running in Windows?

Tags: junit

My spring integration tests are failing due to assertion error on Line separator.
It works fine in the unix environment but when I run in Windows its failing.

The failure is due to difference in the Line separator.

Actual : CRLF
Expected : LF

However the content of the files are identical. Is there anyway we can avoid comparing the line separator ?

Comment: A simple hack: `System.setProperty("line.separator", "\n");` This sets the line separator to LF (Unix-style line endings). You can change "\n" to "\r\n" for CRLF (Windows-style line endings).

Comment: The file is generated at your spring code and you so assert with test file or content in test case? Can you add your test case to get more information?

Comment: You can use assertj `isEqualToIgnoringNewLines`

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring Integration, Spring Boot or Spring at all. The question is more general about cross-platform asserting of the file content. Indeed, see that `isEqualToIgnoringNewLines()` - should be enough.